# Can men wear Steel Watches?

Tags: halal-haram

I know that in Islam, men cannot wear gold and silk. But I want to not know that can men wear steel watches ?

Comment: Men can wear steel watches and silver watches but not gold or silk because that is for women only.

Comment: JazakAllah Khair for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was declared halal at [Darul Ifta](http://www.darulifta-deoband.com/home/en/Clothing--Lifestyle/6031):

> Steel chain is not jewellery; therefore using steel chain watch is allowed.

[Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/87907), [IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=240892), Qibla.com (from [IslamQA.org](http://islamqa.org/hanafi/qibla-hanafi/34667)), and [FatwaIslam](http://www.fatwaislam.com/fis/index.cfm?scn=fd&ID=277) do not disagree.

Problems that can arise are: (a) imitating women ([Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/148059)) for certain styles of watches, and (b) wearing gold watches ([Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/148476)).

Comment: JazakAllah Khair for your answer.